# Is 4 GB of RAM necessary windows phone 8 development?

Tags: windows-phone

It is mentioned on MSDN page,is the requirement strict?My system has 3 GB of RAM and I am not thinking about upgrading my system's ram anytime soon.
Also can I ignore Visual Studio,Windows phone 8 sdk on the whole if I pick up marmalade sdk as the primary development tool?

Answer (score 3):

As someone who has to estimate system requirements with some regularity, I take minimum system requirements with a grain of salt. The minimum requirements have some padding, because nobody really knows where the edge really is, and as estimators we have to play it safe.

Usually, you can get stuff to run even if you don't meet the minimums.

Note that this doesn't mean that it will run *well*.

Not sure about Marmalade.  You should consider separating these two questions into separate postings.

Answer (score 0):

For successfully developing windows phone application minimum hardware requirement is necessary.